# Flatten Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
let list = [
  {
    'items': [
      'item 1',
      'item 2'
    ]
  },
  {
    'items': [
      'item 3'
    ]
  }
]
```

and I want flatten the arrays from this object like this:

```
['item 1','item 2','item 3']
```

Which JavaScript function should I use for this output?

I have tried with the map function:

```
list.map(i => i.items)
```

but I got this output:

```
[["item 1","item 2"],["item 3"]]
```

**NOTE** : I am looking for any existing function or an answer that is wrapped in a function so I can just call a function - not write the loop out myself.

Comment: Use 3rd party libs like https://underscorejs.org/#reduce

Comment: `list.flatMap(i => i.items)`

Comment: *"NOTE : I am looking for any existing function / function chaining if available to get expected output. I am not expecting result by any loop."* There's going to be a loop. The only question is whether it *looks* like a loop, or you hide it in something unnecessarily complicated like `reduce`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know there is always loop behind function but i am expecting the function which is doing loop for me .. I dont want to loop through

Comment: Have you tried reduce method with array result ? and add the items of each item using spread opérator to the result

Comment: @Rajiv - Using the built-in library functions, you'll need at least two loops (Mamun's answer) or an overcomplicated loop-like thing (charlietfl's).

Answer (score 6):

You can flat the `map()` result using [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

> The `flatMap()` method first maps each element using a mapping function, then flattens the result into a new array.

```js
let list = [
  {
    'items': [
      'item 1',
      'item 2'
    ]
  },
  {
    'items': [
      'item 3'
    ]
  }
]
list = list.flatMap(i => i.items);

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Flatmap is not supported by edge nor IE so Hé has to add polyfills to support it, so I think reduce function is better with spread operator

Comment: @mthkhaled - FWIW, Edge will have it soon when it switched over to using V8.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `reduce()`. There is no way to avoid looping since Array prototype methods do loops internally

```js
let list = [
  {
    'items': [
      'item 1',
      'item 2'
    ]
  },
  {
    'items': [
      'item 3'
    ]
  }
];

const res = list.reduce((a,c) => [...a, ...c.items],[])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this:

```js
const list = [{'items': ['item 1','item 2']},{'items': ['item 3']}]

// Using map and flat
console.log(list.map(o => o.items).flat())

// Using flatMap
console.log(list.flatMap(o => o.items))

// Using reduce
console.log(list.reduce((a, o) => a.concat(o.items), []))

// Using a plain old for loop (wrapped in a function)
const getItems = list => {
  let temp = []  
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    const items = list[i].items
    for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
      temp.push(items[j])
    }
  }
  return temp
}
console.log(getItems(list))
```

However, if you want a performance-first solution, reduce + for loop is the way to go:

```js
const list = [{'items': ['item 1','item 2']},{'items': ['item 3']}]

console.log(list.reduce((a, o) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < o.items.length; i++) a.push(o.items[i])
  return a
}, []))
```

Check this [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/map-flat-vs-flatmap-vs-reduce/1) for test cases.

[image: jsperf screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Array.reduce method and follow the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
{
    let list = [
      {
        'items': [
          'item 1',
          'item 2'
        ]
      },
      {
        'items': [
          'item 3'
        ]
      }
    ];

    /**
    * @parameter {Array} arg
    */
    function splat (arg) {
        return arg.reduce((total, { items }) => [...total, ...items], []);
    }

    console.log(splat(list));
}
```

You could also play with recursive function to make a more generic function that accepts array of nested objects.

Answer (score -2):

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#flatten

And

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#flattenDeep

Look like they're exactly what you need.